# Not run more then 60 python file through bash script

Tags: 18.04

we try to run multiple python file through the bas script, but after running 60 py file not started any new py file after 60, and also not opening any terminal. when we check server utilization all are ok. can any one have idea that any limitation for running py file.

Thanks

Comment: The question is unclear unless you show the bash script

Comment: As Archisman said, it is not clear what you mean. What does "run multiple python file through bash" mean? Best is to share your script and describe better what you try to achieve.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.